# Display image from GridFS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, gridfs

I am trying to read image from GridFS. And getting following error.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

exports.getLogo = function (req, res, next) {    


    var conn = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'database-name', 27017);

    conn.once('open', function () {

        var gs = new mongoose.GridStore(conn.db, 'img1.png', "w");

        gs.read(function (err, data) {

            res.setHeader('Content-Type', gs.contentType);
            res.setHeader('Content-Length', gs.length);
            res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="' + gs.filename + '"');

            res.end(data);

        });
    });

};
```

Error :-

```
D:\Projects\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:279
          throw err;
                ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

How to solve this error.

edited -

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'length' of undefined
    at Stream.GridStore.read
```

gridfs-stream output :-

[image]

Comment: where do you the GridStore code? last time check GridStore is not part of mongoose.
both conn and gs need to call open. read the native node.js mongodb doc

Comment: i am using gridFS...http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/gridfs.html

Comment: change var gs = new mongoose.mongo.GridStore(conn.db, 'img1.png', "r");
also read the doc "When GridStore object is created, it needs to be opened".

Comment: thanks..1st error got solved.....i am getting error now `TypeError: Cannot call method 'length' of undefined at Stream.GridStore.read`

Answer (score 2):

you really need to read the doc carefully.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

exports.getLogo = function (req, res, next) {    


    var conn = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'database-name', 27017);

    conn.once('open', function () {

        var gs = new mongoose.mongo.GridStore(conn.db, /* the id */, 'img1.png', "r");
        gs.open(function(err, gs) {
            gs.read(gs.length, function (err, data) {

              res.setHeader('Content-Type', gs.contentType);
              res.setHeader('Content-Length', gs.length);
              // gs don't have a property filename, filename need to come from your req.
              res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="' + 'img1.png' + '"');

              res.end(data);

            });
        })



    });

};
```

Comment: I used this code...it gives no error...But it doesn't send any response...I do have the specified file in my db...

Comment: In Advanced Rest Client...the progress bar keeps moving...!

Comment: did the read function callback executed and the data is not null?

Comment: what i need here is `binary data` of the `image`.....that is what i need to send as response.... i rechecked again....image is present in db...i also tried with another img...stil data shows `null`.

Comment: To open GridStore it require the ObjectId, var gs = new mongoose.mongo.GridStore(conn.db, /* the id */, 'img1.png', "r"); filename is optional. you can specify it in read. It is not very useful then. try this lib https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream

Comment: i am using the same library...it was not giving output so i tried for Gridstore...!

Comment: i posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219400/display-image-in-gridfs