# Display Image in GridFS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, gridfs

I am using gridfs-stream https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream & currently i am on displaying image from gridFS.

When reading data it gives me following output. When i append this data to `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,(data)">`, the image doesn't show.

```
  gfs
// create a read stream from gfs...
.createReadStream({ filename: 'error1.png' })
// and pipe it to Express' response
.pipe(res);
```

Output res :-
[image]

Edited :-

I tried this :-

```
img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + btoa(res);
```

Output rendered is :-

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,W29iamVjdCBPYmplY3Rd">
```

No image shown.

Comment: I think the response is binary data, not base64 encoded, so just try <img src="the link to get the data"

Comment: i experimented....i copied the binary directly from db & appended it in `src` like `data:image/jpeg;base64,(data from db)`....and image got displayed.

Comment: i tried <img src="the link to get the data">.....so in `src` it shows `[object Object]`

Comment: I see what you want to do now, reading the binary data and echo <img right? Convert it to base64 by this: new Buffer('the binary data', 'binary').toString('base64'), and echo src="data:image/png;base64,(data)"

Comment: By using link src, you need a new page which output the data directly, so you can set src="new page output binnary image data"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use file stream demonstrate:

```
var rstream = fs.createReadStream('test.png');

var bufs = [];

rstream.on('data', function(chunk) {

    bufs.push(chunk);

}).on('end', function() { // done

    var fbuf = Buffer.concat(bufs);

    var base64 = (fbuf.toString('base64'));

    res.send('<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64 + '">');
});
```